# How to install Python 3.9.10 inside a container? Can't use the python images

Tags: python, docker

I must run some code inside a container, but the code requires Python 3.9.10, and I am struggling to install version 3.9.10.

I can modify the Dockerfile, but I can't change the base image (which is based on Ubuntu) to python/whatever.

I tried `apt install`, but the installed version is 3.9.5.

I also tried using `conda` to install version 3.9.10 but is incredibly painful to activate its environments automatically.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707223/9267296)?

Comment: I have not, thanks for the suggestion! I check it out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up compiling the version I needed and changing the system defaults, heres my Makefile.

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.2-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04

ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8    

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    git \
    libbz2-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libncursesw5-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxmlsec1-dev \
    llvm \
    make \
    tk-dev \
    wget \
    xz-utils \
    zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# compile python 3.9.10
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/python/cpython.git --branch v3.9.10 \
    && cd /cpython \
    && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3 999 \
    && rm -rf /cpython

# ...
# commands that require both Python 3.9.10 and "nvidia stuff"
# ...
```

Comment: You said "can't change the base image", but here you are using nvidia base container?? Or is this what you were using before?

Comment: This is what I was using before. I said I can't change the base container because people always suggest "just use python slim buster 3.9" or something like that, which I can't do.